# How to create family tree?

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a family tree website, I am using php, mysql and orgChat.js, I have to show the children of a person in this website, then the data of the children of those children and we have to keep doing like this till further. We find out the name of a person's father from the parent_id, for example, if Jon's ID is 1, then the parent_id of his children will be 1. Below I am giving the structure of my table as well as my code.

> I have a problem, currently I am seeing only one branch whereas I have to display all the branches as is happening in the first branch.

**Table Structure**

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jone | null |
| 2 | Max | 1 |
| 3 | Kane | 1 |
| 4 | Gale | 2 |

*Jone is father, Max is son of Jone and Gale is Grand Child of Jone.*

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Family Tree</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.9/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.9/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css">
    <style>
        #chart-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Family Tree</h2>
    <div id="chart-container"></div>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            // Fetch family tree data from PHP script
            $.ajax({
                url: 'fetch_family_tree.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    // Initialize OrgChart
                    $('#chart-container').orgchart({
                        'data': data,
                        'depth': 5, // Set the depth level for better visualization
                        'nodeContent': 'name'
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**fetch_family_tree.php**

```
<?php
// Include the database connection file
include 'db.php';

// Fetch family tree data from the database
$sql = "SELECT id, name, parent_id FROM family_tree";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

// Organize the data into a hierarchical structure
$family_tree = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $parent_id = $row['parent_id'];

    if ($parent_id === NULL) {
        // Root node
        $family_tree[$id] = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $name,
            'children' => array()
        );
    } else {
        // Non-root node
        if (!isset($family_tree[$parent_id]['children'])) {
            $family_tree[$parent_id]['children'] = array();
        }
        $family_tree[$parent_id]['children'][] = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'name' => $name,
            'children' => array() // Initialize children array
        );
    }
}

// Function to recursively add descendants to each node
function addDescendants(&$node, $family_tree) {
    if (isset($node['children'])) {
        foreach ($node['children'] as &$child) {
            if (isset($family_tree[$child['id']]['children'])) {
                addDescendants($family_tree[$child['id']], $family_tree);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Recursively add descendants to each node
foreach ($family_tree as &$node) {
    addDescendants($node, $family_tree);
}

// Close the database connection
mysqli_close($connection);

// Get the root node
$root_node = reset($family_tree);

// Output the root node to start traversal
echo json_encode($root_node);
?>
```

Comment: "Creating a family tree" is a complex task.  your question and title are expected to be narrowed down to a single fundamental problem.  As the family tree grows, it may become too burdensome to fetch all rows from your database.  Your [mcve] should provide clear, minimal sample input data, and the exact desired output data.  If the client-side scripting is irrelevant to your problem, omit it from the question body.

Comment: This kind of questions has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+family+tree) over and over already

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be divided into 2 steps, firstly create a map from `$id` to `$row`

```
$family = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $family[$id] = $row;
}
```

Secondly, it is important to note that `$row` is assigned by reference here. Because arrays are assigned by value by default in PHP, if `&` is not added, `$family[$parent_id]` will be copied as a new array when `&row` is appended to it. I suggest simplifying this process by creating a class (see below)

```
$family_tree = [];
foreach($family as &$row){
    $parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
    if($parent_id != null)
        $family[$parent_id]['children'][] = &$row;
    else
        $family_tree[$id] = &$row;
}
```

---

As mentioned above, you can use `mysqli_fetch_object` to fetch objects, thereby no need to focus on referencing issues, since objects are assigned by reference.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $family[$row->id] = $row;
}

foreach($family as $id => $row){
    $parent_id = $row->parent_id;
    if($parent_id != null)
        $family[$parent_id]->children[] = $row;
    else
        $family_tree[$id] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed to the usual way. But `mysqli_fetch_object` returns stdClass, so it's OK to access fields in array-like syntax.

Comment: No need for stdClass, try `$foo = new stdClass; $foo->props[] = 'bar';`.